# Merging two images ios Swift

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, swift, merge

I am working on iOS 8 app which allows user to simply **merge two existing images into one** and display/save it. But I don't know how to approach this problem. I searched everywhere but didn't find not one solution/example of doing that in **Swift**. There are few similar image processing examples in Objective-C, but they don't answer my question. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I do not know why this question was closed but you can check my repo for merging two images. https://github.com/saqibomer/GiggleMerge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Brad Larson's GPUImage's GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter to accomplish this.

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: Downloaded and tried hard a dozen of Brads GPUImage example, half of them simply crashed... sorry Brad; this answer is way out of date.